# Is there a way to create a selectable item table in excel based on a query?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have a query of group names. I'm attempting to create a table where the groups will be displayed which will allow a user to select certain groups to be included in a new query.  Would a radio button, checkbox, or slicer work?

Original table:

```
let
  itemPOG="SELECT DISTINCT
     POG.DESC10    AS ""GroupName""
    
FROM ADMIN.GROUP POG
INNER JOIN ADMIN.LOCATION POSIT
ON POG.DBKEY = POSIT.PARENTKEY
INNER JOIN ADMIN.INV ITEM
ON ITEM.DBKEY = POSIT.PARENTKEY

WHERE POG.DBSTATUS IN (1)
AND item.""ID"" in (" & #"Old Items In-Line" & ")
;
",
    Source = Odbc.Query("dsn=CKBPRD1_SVC", itemPOG)
in
    Source
```

The final query will be a spread sheet of the selected groups referenced with additional information.

Comment: You tagged for powerquery. Is your Odbc query already being done in powerquery? If so, what code is being used

Comment: Oh sorry.  The ODBC is an oracle database.  For this operation, the data could even be a pivot table made from a list of people and their addresses.  Its just pulling out their group name and then allowing the user to select which group names they want to include in a list of groups that can be referred to for a new query.

Comment: I think i'll probably just need to create a combobox that is populated by the table made from the query.  Then the selections from that box get added to a list.  Then I could query off of that.

Just looking to make it user friendly.  I'm sure i'll figure it out.